# big query load job is stuck forever in running state

Tags: google-bigquery

I pushed NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON file that has just **3 lines** into bigquery table. It has been **45 minutes** already and I still see the job in the console in running state.

Job id is civil-decoder-592:bqjob_r59aff6939d9c423a_00000146895ab2a9_1  Can you please take a look?

Comment: I have the same error. Also a JSON file....
Looks like a bigger issue.

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like an error to me. My load finished successfully after 4 hr.

Comment: It was this a joke?

Comment: I didn't use BQ for a while.
Back then BQ sometimes had erroneous long running jobs, that after incredible long running time return successful.